# Automorphic representations for two number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

I have a basic question that I have not found a reference for: how are the automorphic representations of a reductive group $G$ for two different number fields $K \supset K'$ related? For example, if $K$ is a quadratic field, how are automorphic representations of $GL(n)$ over $K$ related to those for $\mathbb{Q}$? Thanks!

Comment: It's expected that you have a map from automorphic representations of GL(n) over K to representations over K'. This isn't known in general, but is for cyclic extensions (e.g., your quadratic extensions). The phrases to search for are "cyclic base change" and "Langlands functoriality."

Comment: There is a nice account of this for the simplest non-trivial case -- that is, $n = 2$, $K' = \mathbf{Q}$, and $K$ real quadratic (due to Doi and Nagunuma) -- in Bump's book "Automorphic Forms and Representations", section I.7.